# How can I properly escape a CircleCI parameter to use it inside a JSON string?

Tags: bash, circleci

I have a CircleCI command wrapping [`slack/notify`](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/slack). Let's simplify it to

```
commands:
  slack-message:
    parameters:
      message:
        type: string
    steps:
      - slack/notify:
          custom: |
            {
              "blocks": [
                {
                  "type": "section",
                  "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "Some additional information << parameters.message >>"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

This fails when `message` includes e.g. a linebreak. My current attempt to fix it is

```
commands:
  slack-message:
    parameters:
      message:
        type: string
    steps:
      - run
          name: Set up environment
          command:
            MESSAGE="<< parameters.message >>"
            echo export MESSAGE=${MESSAGE@Q} >> $BASH_ENV
      - slack/notify:
          custom: |
            {
              "blocks": [
                {
                  "type": "section",
                  "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "Some additional information $MESSAGE"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

but it will similarly fail if the message includes double quotes. I also tried adding

```
    environment:
      MESSAGE_PARAM: << parameters.message >>
```

to the command before `steps`, but this didn't work:

```
ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/commands/slack-message] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
1. [#/commands/slack-message] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   Command may be a string reference to another command
2. [#/commands/slack-message] extraneous key [environment] is not permitted
```

CircleCI config version is 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

To fix my double-quote concern, the fix is indeed

```
    environment:
      MESSAGE_PARAM: << parameters.message >>
```

but I put it in the wrong place. It should be

```
      - run
          name: Set up environment
          environment:
            MESSAGE_PARAM: << parameters.message >>
          command:
            echo export MESSAGE=${MESSAGE_PARAM@Q} >> $BASH_ENV
```

instead. I'll test if more escaping is needed later.